# Footnotemark and footnotetext on different pages

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes

Is there a way to permit footnotes to begin on a page subsequent to the one on which they were invoked? If the footnote is separated by no more than 1 page from the invoking line of text, then this is acceptable and even desirable in certain circumstances. Please see the MWE below to get an idea of document layout problems engendered by demanding footnotes be placed on the same page as the invoking text.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}
    This line gets broken across two pages in order to accomodate long footnotes. %
    Preferably, the second footnote would not obligatorily begin on the %
    same page as the first footnote. This would avoid awkwardly large blank pages.%
    \footnote{The footnote itself has a footnote.\footnotemark%
    \lipsum}%
    \footnotetext{\lipsum}%
    \end{document}
```

Note: I do not wish to use endnotes because footnotes avoid the problem of having to flip/scroll to the end of the document. I merely wish to alter the properties of footnote placement to avoid large spaces that are incurred by the requirement for footnotes to be placed on the invoking page.

Note: the command `\interfootnotelinepenalty=0` does not resolve the problem as this parameter affects whether a footnote is permitted to break across pages, not whether a footnote is allowed to begin on a different page than the invoking page.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

There is no requirement for the `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext{<text>}` to be on the same page. You can either issue a `\clearpage` to flush all content and typeset `\footnotetext{<text>}` on the following page, or you could automatically have it set on the following page using [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
This line gets broken across two pages in order to accomodate long footnotes. %
Preferably, the second footnote would not obligatorily begin on the %
same page as the first footnote. This would avoid awkwardly large blank pages.%
\footnote{The footnote itself has a footnote.\footnotemark%
\lipsum}%
\AtBeginShipoutNext{\footnotetext{\lipsum}}% Typeset footnote on following page
\ \lipsum
\end{document}
```

`atbegshi` provides `\AtBeginShipoutNext{<stuff>}` which delays execution of `<stuff>` in the above case, since the page is already assembled for shipout, and subsequently flushed to the following page. More text follows the after the "delayed `\footnotetext`", just to show how text flow is maintained.

Comment: Thanks, just so I understand, this is applied on an ad hoc basis to force lines to flush to a subsequent page? If correct, then it seems best to add these commands after the document is finalized because editing may alter the positions at which these commands should be invoked. For instance, if I add an `\AtBeginShipoutNext` command and then later add more text prior to that command, then I may have to readjust placement of these functions. Is there a global way to implement this type of feature so the compiler "intelligently" places footnotes (e.g., by heavily penalizing large blank spaces).

Comment: @user001: In my opinion, yes. Your MWE clearly shows a problem, but this may be of no concern in a realistic setting. Many things, footnote placement included, is dependent on page content and proximity to the page boundary. As such, leave them until the final production to sort out any left-over kinks. Not sure whether *this* or my answer answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the hyperref-package, you could alternatively try the following code (with one nested footnote, Werner's approach works fine, but I'm not sure of that in case of more footnotes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tablefootnote}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\spewnotes}{%
\tfn@tablefootnoteprintout%
\global\let\tfn@tablefootnoteprintout\relax%
\gdef\tfn@fnt{0}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}% if you like to have hyperlinks, otherwise omit it

\begin{document}
This line gets broken across two pages in order to accommodate long footnotes. %
Preferably, the second footnote would not obligatorily begin on the %
same page as the first footnote. This would avoid awkwardly large blank pages.%
\footnote{The footnote itself has a footnote.\tablefootnote{\lipsum}%
\AtBeginShipoutNext{\spewnotes}% Typeset footnote on following page
\lipsum}%
\ \lipsum
\end{document}
```