# Why don't footnotes appear at the bottom of the page?

Tags: footnotes, epub, php

With this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{I}
Suonava la messa dell’alba\footnotemark[1] a San
Giovanni; ma il paesetto dormiva ancora della grossa, perché era
piovuto da tre giorni, e nei seminati ci si affondava fino a mezza
gamba. Tutt’a un tratto, nel silenzio, s’udì un rovinìo, la campanella
squillante di Sant’Agata\footnotemark[2] che chiamava aiuto, usci e
finestre che sbattevano, la gente che scappava fuori in camicia,
gridando:\par
% other many paragraphs here
%at the end of the chapter the footnotes
\footnotetext[1]{  Suonava la campana che annunciava la messa
dell’alba.\par }
\footnotetext[2]{  Della chiesa di Sant’Agata.\par }
%etc.
\end{document}
```

I want the footnotes to appear at the bottom of every page and not at the end of the chapter.

I've tried to add `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` in the preamble but it didn't work.
I'm using Overleaf, with default settings

[image: first page]

[image: second-last page]

[image: last page]

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just use `\footnote{...text...}`?

Comment: Yes, I generate the tex file with php from an epub where the notes are at the end of every chapter.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your result? If I run your code and add a few more paragraphs to get a second page, the footnotes are still at the bottom of the first page.

Comment: Fair enough, it may be an issue with how you are compiling it then, could you link to a website or describe how you are compiling it with an edit to your question please so others can reproduce?

Comment: I *can* reproduce your problem (unlike @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz). If I run your code with a few more paragraphs inserted *before* the group of `\footnotetext`s, the footnotes are typeset on the *last* page, just as in your example.

Comment: I'm using Overleaf, with default settings and not in draft mode

Comment: So sometimes you want the footnotes at the end of the chapter, and others you don't? `\let\footnote=\endnote` and use `\printnotes` at the end of each chapter (enotez package).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(edited to provide a bit more information about how the TeX/LaTeX page builder algorithm works and how this matters for the OP's issue)

> I want the footnotes to appear at the bottom of every page and not at the end of the chapter.

The TeX/LaTeX page builder algorithm is "greedy", in the sense that it finishes a page and ships it out (generally, but not necessarily, to a pdf file) as soon as it can do so. This implies that if the `\footnotetext` directives are delayed until the end of a chapter, LaTeX has absolutely no way of going back a few pages and "doing over" the pages that happen to contain the `\footnotemark` directives that correspond to the delayed `\footnotetext` directives.

Rather than place the `\footnotetext` directives at the very end of a chapter, I suggest you insert them immediately after the corresponding `\footnotemark` instructions.

I've highlighted the footnote markers in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{I}

Suonava la messa dell'alba%
\footnotemark[1]%
\footnotetext[1]{Suonava la campana che annunciava la messa dell'alba.}
a San Giovanni; ma il paesetto dormiva ancora della grossa, perché era piovuto da tre giorni, e nei seminati ci si affondava fino a mezza gamba. Tutt'a un tratto, nel silenzio, s'udì un rovinìo, la campanella squillante di Sant'Agata%
\footnotemark[2]%
\footnotetext[2]{Della chiesa di Sant'Agata.}
che chiamava aiuto, usci e finestre che sbattevano, la gente che scappava fuori in camicia, gridando:

\lipsum[1-4] % about a page worth of filler text

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Btw, is the behavior OP is experiencing actually the expected behavior? I.e., is it normal for `\footnotetext` to print the text on the page where *it* is invoked (and not where `\footnotemark` is called)? [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39401/) seems to say as much ("There is no requirement for the \footnotemark and \footnotetext{<text>} to be on the same page.")
If so, it might be worth mentioning!

Comment: @marquinho - I have no way of knowing what the OP expects or doesn't expect. I suppose the point of being able to place the text of a footnote on a different page than where the footnote markers occurs is to gain some extra placement flexibility, should there be a use case for it. As it would appear that the OP doesn't need this extra degree of flexibility, I'm suggesting they just bundle the `\foonotemark` and `footnotetext` directives.

Comment: Yes, but the tex file is generated with php from an epub where the notes are at the end of every chapter, so I prefer to find another solution. Anyway, this will be my last attempt, thanks.

Comment: @AlbertoArdito - The LaTeX page builder algorithm is "greedy", in the sense that it finishes a page and ships it out (generally to a pdf file) as soon as it can do so. If the `\footnotetext` directives are delayed until the end of a chapter, LaTeX has absolutely no way of going back however many pages may be needed and "doing over" the pages that happen to contain the `\footnotemark` directives that correspond to the delayed `\footnotetext` directives.

Comment: @Mico: Sorry for being unclear :) What I meant by "expected behavior" is "what should I normally expect when I use `\footnotetext` in LaTeX?" You answered this in your latest comment: LaTeX can't go back and rebuild an earlier page to insert the footnotes. I believe OP was "expecting" the opposite when they placed `\footnotetext` at the end but hoped for the text to print at the start. Therefore, your comment would be a good addition to the answer: "That cannot be done, because of LaTeX' algorithm".

Comment: @marquinho - Good suggestion! I'll go ahead ahead and provide the missing explanation in the body of the answer.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to write a php script to replace every mark with a `\footnote` with the relative note. Thanks for the explanation